# iTerm2 Transparent transparent background for inactive windows

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, iterm

The native `MacOS Terminal` has an ability to set transparency for both in-active and active panes. iTerm2 has the transparency for active backgrounds, for some reason, I can't find the inactive one or `maybe there isn't any?`. I am aware that, iTerm2 has the `DIM inactive split panes` but what I am looking for is transparency.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a dimming amount bar that you can adjust for inactive split panes. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @yash where exactly is it?

Comment: it's under Preferences -> Appearance -> Dimming. i am linking a screenshot for you https://ibb.co/dohF6S

Answer (score 97):

Found the answer on [this blog](https://blog.sujithg.com/2016/06/24/Transparent-iTerm2-on-a-mac/) but I'll repeat it here for the sake of preservation.

1. Open iTerm2's preferences, using the menu or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. Select **Profiles** from the menu bar
3. Select the **Window** tab
4. Drag the transparency slider to suit your needs
   [image: iTerm2 transparency control]

Comment: This affects all windows including the active ones, the OP wants to change transparency only of _inactive_ ones.

Comment: not working for me...I'm changing transparency but iterm2 windows remain opaque...Any idea?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants the behavior that the Mac terminal has: add transparency to inactive windows. AFAICS this is not possible but @bjfletcher's answer is closer.

Comment: also wasnt working for when setting up a new machine. I somewhere read you have to then press cmd+B and voila, it worked ! (cannot remember having had to do this on my old machine back in the days)

Answer (score 18):

Preferences → Appearance → Dimming → Dimming amount

[image]

Comment: Close substitute, but this isn't exactly the same.  It applies dimming (like a gray cast), not an opaque on click effect and transparent while inactive effect.

Answer (score 4):

Update: I put the two scripts up on [GitHub](https://github.com/dfpetrin/iterm2-auto-transparency-toggle), along with a nice demo GIF :)

Also did a bit of refactor and bug fixing.  Check out the repo for the up-to-date scripts.

[image: Demo toggling the transparency of two iTerm2 windows]

---

Each of the previous answers gets a piece of the puzzle. One changes transparency, but is static; the other dims when windows are inactive, rather than changes transparency.

To get the desired behavior (change transparency based on window focus), you need to write a script using iTerm2's Python API, and save it as an AutoLaunch script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import iterm2

# Store window change event reason objects in more convenient variables
window_selected = [iterm2.FocusUpdateWindowChanged.Reason.TERMINAL_WINDOW_BECAME_KEY]


async def update_tab_transparency(connection, tab, reason):
    # Apply to any and all sessions in tab
    for session in tab.sessions:
        profile = await session.async_get_profile()
        change = iterm2.LocalWriteOnlyProfile()

        # For window change events bringing a window into focus,
        # change transparency to zero
        if reason in window_selected:
            change.set_transparency(0)

        # For window change events taking a window out of focus,
        # make sure transparency matches the original profile
        else:
            # But, only need to do anything if the profile has been changed
            # from the original
            if profile.original_guid:
                original = await iterm2.Profile.async_get(
                    connection, [profile.original_guid]
                )
                change.set_transparency(original[0].transparency)

        await session.async_set_profile_properties(change)


async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)

    # Initialize for first window
    window = app.current_window
    if window and window.current_tab:
        tab = window.current_tab
        reason = window_selected[0]
        await update_tab_transparency(connection, tab, reason)

    async with iterm2.FocusMonitor(connection) as mon:
        while True:
            # Block until a tab or window change
            update = await mon.async_get_next_update()

            # When switching to a new tab, treat as selecting a window
            if update.selected_tab_changed:
                tab = app.get_tab_by_id(update.selected_tab_changed.tab_id)
                reason = window_selected[0]

            # For window change events, use the provided event reason
            elif update.window_changed:
                window = app.get_window_by_id(update.window_changed.window_id)
                tab = window.current_tab
                reason = update.window_changed.event

            # For other focus change events, do nothing
            else:
                continue

            if tab:
                await update_tab_transparency(connection, tab, reason)


iterm2.run_forever(main)
```

See the iTerm docs for details on [using Python scripts](https://iterm2.com/python-api/)

You want to set the desired transparency on your profile, and check the "Use transparency" box for "Settings for New Windows".  This sounds counter-intuitive, but toggling that "Use transparency" setting doesn't seem to be possible via the API, so the script instead quickly switches windows to opaque on creation.

At least on my machine the window flickers briefly when first selected, but I'm not sure if there's anything I can do about that.

---

Note: macOS currently (11.6, Big Sur) treats windows the opposite of this—it makes active windows transparent (at least, certain parts of them) and inactive ones opaque (and faded).  Try opening a new tab in Safari.  It makes sense!  The transparency creats a sense of depth.  Seeing that there are windows behind the active one emphasizes that it's in front of them.

To get this behavior instead, use the following script.  This variant is both simpler, and seems to run more smoothly (no flickering).  It works best if you have the blur cranked to max, and transparency ~25.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import iterm2

# Store window change event reason objects in more convenient variables
window_selected = [iterm2.FocusUpdateWindowChanged.Reason.TERMINAL_WINDOW_BECAME_KEY]


async def update_tab_transparency(connection, tab, reason):
    # Apply to any and all sessions in tab
    for session in tab.sessions:
        profile = await session.async_get_profile()
        change = iterm2.LocalWriteOnlyProfile()

        # For window change events bringing a window into focus,
        # make sure transparency matches the original profile
        if reason in window_selected:
            # But, only need to do anything if the profile has been changed
            # from the original
            if profile.original_guid:
                original = await iterm2.Profile.async_get(
                    connection, [profile.original_guid]
                )
                change.set_transparency(original[0].transparency)

        # For window change events taking a window out of focus,
        # change transparency to zero
        else:
            change.set_transparency(0)

        await session.async_set_profile_properties(change)


async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)

    async with iterm2.FocusMonitor(connection) as mon:
        while True:
            # Block until a window change
            update = await mon.async_get_next_update()
            if update.window_changed:
                window = app.get_window_by_id(update.window_changed.window_id)
                tab = window.current_tab

                if tab:
                    reason = update.window_changed.event
                    await update_tab_transparency(connection, tab, reason)


iterm2.run_forever(main)
```

Comment: Derrik: just to let you know I've been running with your second script for a few days and it's great.

Comment: That's great to hear! If you have any suggestions/fixes, please share them. I have noticed sometimes when I close tabs I get a notification that the script crashed, but it doesn't seem to affect runtime behavior of other tabs, so I haven't bothered to dig into it.

Comment: Ok update: I fixed that bug (there were actually two), did some refactoring, and put it all up on github :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a script for anyone that need a script for changing the transparency of the active, and all the inactive, panes/sessions – rather than just for entire windows. It's working both for multiple windows and split panes. Here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BlackZoda/iTermScripts).

Personally I use it in full screen mode with split panes – so I easily can see referance material through the inactive panes, while still keeping the active pane legible.

Feel free to shout out if you got any questions or suggestions, and hope this helps! :)

Edit: Here's the code from the script in the repo mentioned above. Feel free to remove the code using `settings.json` – if not, you can create a *settings.json* file like this in the iTerm2 Scripts folder `(/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/iTerm2/Scripts)`:

```json
{
    "pane_transparency": {
        "active": 0.2,
        "inactive": 0.8,
        "blur": false,
        "blur_radius": 0
    }
}
```

Can remove the blur stuff if you don't want it as well (have to apply it for every pane, tab and window).

As mentioned above, you can read about how to set up scripts in iTerm2's official [documentation](https://iterm2.com/python-api/tutorial/index.html). Should run the script as a daemon (from the `./AutoLaunch` folder).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import iterm2
import json
import os

# Global settings
SETTINGS_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../settings.json')

# Default pane transparency settings (overridden by settings.json)
DEFAULT_TRANSPARENCY_ACTIVE = 0.25
DEFAULT_TRANSPARENCY_INACTIVE = 0.75
DEFAULT_BLUR = False
DEFAULT_BLUR_RADUIUS = 0

async def load_settings():
    """Load settings from the settings.json file."""

    with open(SETTINGS_FILE) as f:
        settings = json.load(f)

    pane_transparency = settings.get("pane_transparency", {})

    transparancy_active = pane_transparency.get("active", DEFAULT_TRANSPARENCY_ACTIVE)
    transparancy_active = transparancy_active if (0 <= transparancy_active <= 1) else DEFAULT_TRANSPARENCY_ACTIVE

    transparency_inactive = pane_transparency.get("inactive", DEFAULT_TRANSPARENCY_INACTIVE)
    transparency_inactive = transparency_inactive if (0 <= transparency_inactive <= 1) else DEFAULT_TRANSPARENCY_INACTIVE

    blur = pane_transparency.get("blur", DEFAULT_BLUR)
    blur = blur if blur == True or False else DEFAULT_BLUR

    blur_radius = pane_transparency.get("blur_radius", DEFAULT_BLUR_RADUIUS)
    blur_radius = blur_radius if (isinstance(blur_radius, int) and 0 <= blur_radius <= 30) else DEFAULT_BLUR_RADUIUS

    return transparancy_active, transparency_inactive, blur, blur_radius

async def transparancy_update(
        app,
        active_session,
        transparency_active,
        transparency_inactive,
        blur,
        blur_radius):
    """Updating the transparency for the active and all inactive panes."""

    inactive_change = iterm2.LocalWriteOnlyProfile()
    inactive_change.set_transparency(transparency_inactive)

    active_change = iterm2.LocalWriteOnlyProfile()
    active_change.set_transparency(transparency_active)
    active_change.set_blur(blur)
    active_change.set_blur_radius(blur_radius)

    # Updates all inactive panes
    await transparancy_update_inactive(app, active_session, inactive_change)

    # Updates the the active pane
    await active_session.async_set_profile_properties(active_change)

async def transparancy_update_inactive(app, active_session, inactive_change):
    """Updating the transparency for all inactive panes."""

    # Looping over all inactive panes and changing transparency
    for window in app.terminal_windows:
            for tab in window.tabs:
                for session in tab.all_sessions:
                    if session != active_session:
                        await session.async_set_profile_properties(inactive_change)

async def main(connection):
    """Pane transparency main method"""

    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)

    transparency_active, transparency_inactive, blur, blur_radius = await load_settings()

    async with iterm2.FocusMonitor(connection) as mon:
        active_session = app.current_terminal_window.current_tab.current_session
        while True:
            update = await mon.async_get_next_update()

            if update.active_session_changed:
                active_session = app.get_session_by_id(update.active_session_changed.session_id)

            if update.active_session_changed or update.selected_tab_changed:
                await transparancy_update(
                    app,
                    active_session,
                    transparency_active,
                    transparency_inactive,
                    blur,
                    blur_radius)

iterm2.run_forever(main)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34696800)

Comment: Updated the post with the relevant code from the repo.